# How to fetch Records for a week

Tags: java, date, jdbc

I am using Java 7 and fetching records for a week.For **valid_from** column I am subtracting `-7` from current date below. The format of date in DB is `12-FEB-18`. For **valid_to** column I am using sysdate. I am not getting correct **valid_from** date. Can anyone review this what is wrong here.

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
Date todate1 = cal.getTime();
Date startdate = ((DateFormat)formatter).parse(formatter.format(todate1));
System.out.println(todayWithZeroTime);

String sql_qry = "SELECT a.ACCOUNT_ID from tableName a where a.STATUS_TYPE_KEY='ACTIVE' "
    + "and a.VALID_FROM >"
    + startdate+ " and a.VALID_TO > sysdate";
```

How can I parse only Date here. Currently I am getting `Tue Feb 13 00:00:00 GMT 2018`. I want `13-FEB-18` which I can send as variable in where condition.
Please suggest

Comment: I think you want to have a `?` placeholder in your query and then set the actual start date with (Java 7) `yourPreparedStatement.setDate` or (Java 8) `yourPreparedStatement.setObject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting a `Date`  to a `String` then back to a `Date`.

Then you are using this `Date` object in your query, so it's `toString()` method gets called and yields a `String` representation which is probably not the one you wanted.

Avoid the last conversion from `String` to `Date`  and just use

`String startdate = formatter.format(todate1);`

Note that you also have to escape the date string with quotes :

```
 String sql_qry = "SELECT a.ACCOUNT_ID from tableName a where "
                 + "a.STATUS_TYPE_KEY='ACTIVE' "
                 + "and a.VALID_FROM > '"
                 + startdate+ "' and a.VALID_TO > sysdate";
```

Also consider having a look at [Java time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) and at [How to use PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: I tried that only but unfortunately I get error Invalid column as it is expecting Date not string.I suppose.SO I tried sending Date to the select statement

Comment: You are using string concatenation, so it ends up being a string anyway. See  the updated answer, it seems some quotes were missing .

Comment: thanks a lot.Can you help me with startdate and enddate in a scenerio where everytime the startdate and enddate will be on week basis like above but only the first time execution I want data for 5 years.Like from date=1-JAN-13 and todate=sysdate and then afterwards weekly data.

Comment: @Lisa14 : Consider creating a new question to explain what you want to do and so that other people may help . It is not very clear at the moment.